# What is the difference between None and boolean (True, False) in python's default argument values?

Tags: python

In function definitions, one can define a boolean default argument's values as `argument=None` or `argument=False`.

An example from pandas concat:

```
def concat(
    objs,
    axis=0,
    join="outer",
    join_axes=None,
    ignore_index=False,
    keys=None,
    levels=None,
    names=None,
    verify_integrity=False,
    sort=None,
    copy=True,
):
```

While both usages can be found, why would one be using one over the other?

Is there any PEP on this?

Comment: Those are default argument values, not keyword arguments. Keyword arguments are something you use when calling a function, not something that happens at definition time. Whether an argument has a default is completely unrelated to whether you can (or must) pass the argument by keyword.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`True` and `False` are specific `bool` values. Use default `False` when you have a `bool` field and you want the default to be `False.`Don't use `False` as a value for a non-`bool` field.

`None` is used as a generic placeholder when the value will be set later. It can be typed as `Optional[T]`, which is equivalent to `Union[T, None]`.

You might be thinking of `None` and `False` as similar because they're both "falsy" (`bool(x)` returns `False`), but the same is true of several other values, `[] () {} 0 0.0`, etc and we don't use them like `None` either.

In your example, `True`/`False` are used where the field takes a boolean value. `None` is used where the field takes an `Optional[List]`. (The exception is `sort: Optional[bool]`, which is being used temporarily as an ad-hoc compatibility tool for a deprecated behavior.)

Comment: thanks, what does `Optional[List]` and `sort: Optional[bool]` mean?

Comment: `Optional[List]` means the value can be either a `list` or `None`. `sort: Optional[bool]` means the `sort` argument to [`pandas.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) can be a `bool` or `None`. The notation comes from [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 2):

`True` and `False` are boolean values, so in this context `None` can make sense if you have a boolean variable that can be in an 'unknown' state. Strictly spoken, such a variable would not be boolean, but in reality, this can be quite handy.

For example:

```
# In the beginning, we simply don't know if it's true or not
is_cat_alive = None

# But later we will determine the status
is_cat_alive = check_cat_in(box)
```

Note that if you are using a boolean like this, then `if is_cat_alive` will be false when `is_cat_alive` is *either* `False` *or* `None` which makes sense but might not be what you want to know. So to explicitly check for a dead cat, you would have to use `if is_cat_alive == False`.

Answer (score 0):

`None` is similar to a null value if you know anything about those. Someone might say it's equal to 0, but None means that it is nothing. Say `age = None` for example. age is a variable, but it is equal to nothing. False is an actual value. True and False can be used as an indicator such as

```
def name_check(name)
    if name == "Brittany":
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Calling that function with "Brittany" as the name parameter would return True which could be used in other conditions as well. Hope this helped! Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Look at the following code:

```
my_string = ''
my_other_string = None
my_final_string = 'I am a string'
```

If you were using these within python in something like an if statement they would actually equal the following:

```
my_string = False
my_other_string = None
my_final_string = True
```

Hope that helps